# How can I mock the HttpUrlConnection.getResponseCode() method using EasyMock

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I am trying to write test case for below code snippet. But mock is not working as expected.

```
Map<String, String> request = new HAshMap<String, String>();
URL url = new URL("sampleurl");
HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) url.openConnection();

if(connection != null){
connection.setDOutput(true);

OutputStreamReader out = new OutputStreamReader(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(new Gson().toJson(request);
out.close();

int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
}
```

I have tried the below test code snippet for mocking but Mock is not working properly, where I am doing wrong

```
 URL url = PowerMock.createNiceMock(URL.class);
 HttpsUrlConnection httpConn = PowerMock.createNiceMock(HttpsUrlConnection.class);

 EasyMock.expect(url.openConnection()).andReturn(httpConn);
 EasyMock.expect(httpConn.getResponseCode()).andReturn(500);
```

Comment: You create new url: `URL url = new URL("sampleurl");` You are not using your mocked instance in method under test.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is right. A mock needs to be injected. I highly recommend that you document yourself on the concept first.

In your case, objects are created in the method, so normally, we would say it can't be mocked. From a separation of concerns, this method is doing too many things.

If we want to keep the same code and go the PowerMock way, it will look like this. I'll give you my tested class and my test.

```
public class MyClass {

    public int call() throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> request = new HashMap<>();
        URL url = new URL("sampleurl");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        return connection.getResponseCode();
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyClass.class, URL.class})
public class MyClassTest {

    private MyClass testClass = new MyClass();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        URL url = PowerMock.createMock(URL.class);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = PowerMock.createMock(HttpURLConnection.class);

        PowerMock.expectNew(URL.class, "sampleurl").andReturn(url);
        EasyMock.expect(url.openConnection()).andReturn(httpConn);
        EasyMock.expect(httpConn.getResponseCode()).andReturn(500);

        PowerMock.replayAll();

        assertThat(testClass.call()).isEqualTo(500);
    }
}
```

But I would actually never code such a thing. I would refactor with a better design. Possibly having another class to create the connection. If I'm refactoring, the minimum would be:

```
public class MyClass {

    public int call() throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> request = new HashMap<>();
        HttpURLConnection connection = getConnection();
        return connection.getResponseCode();
    }

    HttpURLConnection getConnection() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("sampleurl");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        return connection;
    }
}

public class MyOtherTest extends EasyMockSupport {

    private MyClass testClass = partialMockBuilder(MyClass.class)
            .addMockedMethod("getConnection")
            .mock();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        expect(httpConn.getResponseCode()).andReturn(500);
        expect(testClass.getConnection()).andReturn(httpConn);

        replayAll();

        assertThat(testClass.call()).isEqualTo(500);
    }
}
```